# Invalid syntax error while running unit test in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, format-string

my sample django project works fine and i get result but the problem is that whenever i run unit test on my project i get syntax error as follows in test.py. i have tried using .format() still it shows up error .why cant i use f'this is my text' to format my string ?                                        **error log**

```
ERROR: blog.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: blog.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in
  _get_module_from_name
__import__(name)
File "/home/blog/tests.py", line 28
self.assertEqual(f'{self.post.title}', 'Content')
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: can you mention your tests also ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f-strings are valid in Python 3.6+ only.

However there doesn't seem to be any reason to use them here, since you're not interpolating anything. Why not just `self.assertEqual(self.post.title, 'Content')`?

Comment: One might point out that this assumes that `self.post.title` is a `str` to begin with (which seems a reasonable assumption).

Comment: Yeah, true. If not, `str(self.post.title)` is still a better bet.